# assign member of the derived class to another of the derived class

Tags: c++

i have a question about assigning one member of the derived class to another of the same derived class,
Can someone please help me understand why this code is printing 14 and not 34?
i dont understand when b2.nb is getting the value of b1.nb, because in this code:

```
   A& operator=(const A& a){
        na = a.na*2;
        return *this;
    }
```

there is no assignment of  b1.nb to b2.nb

```
class A{
public:
    A(int i){na = i;}
    A& operator=(const A& a){
        na = a.na*2;
        return *this;
    }
    int na;
};

class B : public A{
public:
    B(int i, int j): A(j){nb = i;}
    int nb;
};

int main()
{
   B b1(1,2);
   B b2(3,4);
   b2 = b1;
   cout<<b2.nb<<b2.na;
}
```

Comment: It's getting it from the object that's assigned to it.

Comment: yes but in the operator overloading function there is no assignment of b2

Comment: What operator overloading? A very careful inspection of the shown code does not find any overloaded operators for the `B` class.

Comment: @bjosujs: is your question answered?  Specifically, do you understand the problem was that "B" doesn't automagically "inherit" your overload for "A operator=", so the assignment "b2 = b1" didn't have the effect you expected?  If you have further questions, please ask.  Otherwise, please consider "upvoting" and "accepting" Silvio Mayolo's reply below.

Answer (score 5):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment)

> ## Implicitly-declared copy assignment operator
>
> If no user-defined copy assignment operators are provided for a class type (`struct`, `class`, or `union`), the compiler will always declare one as an inline public member of the class.

Your `B` class never declares a copy assignment operator (i.e. an operator with a signature compatible with `B& operator=(const B&)`). The fact that `A` does is irrelevant here. `B` does not declare one, so C++ generates one. That generated copy assignment operator calls the parent class' assignment operator and then assigns any variables declared in `B` directly, in your case `nb`.